# APFS Container Resize error code is 49187

Tags: macos, partition, macos-high-sierra

When I try to create/resize partition via **Disk Utility** or **Terminal** I get an error: 
`APFS Container Resize error code is 49187`

Also I stopped **Time Machine**, deleted all snapshots, but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

**From Disk Utility**
[image]

**From Terminal**
[image]

Comment: 1. I'd recommend to move the question to superuser.com. 2. I found out that the error will only occur if I try to use a new size **less than 230GB**. so all you need is to use any size **larger than 230GB**. 3. see example how to do it manually here - https://superuser.com/questions/1270251/resizing-windows-10-bootcamp-partition-manually